# My rowfilter works fine on one DataTable but not on the other

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, dataview, rowfilter

I am using an Access database with multiple tables. Each table is displayed in a separate Datagrid.

Now I wanted to filter each table with their own corresponding TextBox using the following code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(myDataSet.table1);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("columnToFilter LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    table1DataGrid.DataContext = DV;
}
```

For the second table I use exactly the same code.

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(myDataSet.table2);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("columnToFilter LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox2.Text);
    table2DataGrid.DataContext = DV;
}
```

The filter works fine for `table1`. As soon as I start typing in `textBox1` the displayed DataGrid automatically updates. However when I type something in `textBox2` nothing happens.

Can somebody help me figure out why the second filter doesn't work?

Comment: Have you ensured, that there is any data in myDataSet.table2?

Comment: Did you use the debugger to make sure that the 2nd event is enterd?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: I can confirm both tables contain data and I placed a breakpoint in the textChanged event to see if this bit of code is entered, which it is. During running the program with the breakpoint I also looked at the Autos tab (bottem left in Visual Studio) and saw that all the variables contain similar data for both filters. (Excuse my terminology, I am new to c#)